# "go / on a picnic" or "go on / a picnic"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> 'go on a picnic' is a very famous phrase.

I wonder where the meaning group is separated?

1. go on + a picnic
2. go + on a picnic

ps. another example is "go on a business trip"

Comment: It's a common expression, I wouldn't say it's *famous*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "go" is the verb. The rest is where you go.

> Go on a date.
>
> Go to the movies.
>
> Go about your business.
>
> Go from here to there.

In this one I think the verb is "go on"

> Go on to the next step in the instructions.

Comment: What about go on a picnic? 'go on' is a verb or 'go' is a verb and the rest is where you go? It was my question.

Comment: I think it's "Go (on a picnic)" as my first four examples suggest.